# How to force the Mac to not expire passwords?

Tags: macos, security, password

This morning, when I logged into my Mac, it forced me to change my password. Because I'm unlikely to remember a new password, I had to choose an insecure password that will be easier to remember.

It also won't let me change the password back.

I went to the Security & Privacy settings and found NOTHING that can control this behavior.

Everything on the Internet that is even remotely related is about Active Directory, but I'm sure this thing isn't using Active Directory.

How do you make a Mac NOT do this?

Comment: Is it a managed, work machine, etc, or does it use your AppleID as sign-in? In 25 years of using Macs I've never had one force a password change on me.

Comment: Please open Terminal and enter `pwpolicy -u your_username --get-effective-policy` and add the result to your question.

Comment: @Tetsujin You can also set a local password policy with `(sudo) pwpolicy ...`. A pw reset is not necessarily related to OD or AD - but very, very uncommon in a normal consumer environment!

Comment: @klanomath, `pwpolicy -u your_username --get-effective-policy` didn't print anything relevant (and the man page says `--get-effective-policy` is deprecated), but you led me in the right direction, and I've found the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @klanomath I just posted it.

Answer (score 8):

The feature is controlled by a tool called `pwpolicy`. Running `pwpolicy -getaccountpolicies` outputs an XML document. One of the things found in this XML is this:

```
<key>policyCategoryPasswordChange</key>
<array>
        <dict>
                <key>policyContent</key>
                <string>policyAttributeCurrentTime &gt; policyAttributeLastPasswordChangeTime + (policyAttributeExpiresEveryNDays * 24 * 60 * 60)</string>
                <key>policyIdentifier</key>
                <string>ProfilePayload:deadbeef-b187-1337-1ee7-abcdef123456:maxPINAgeInDays</string>
                <key>policyParameters</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>policyAttributeExpiresEveryNDays</key>
                        <integer>90</integer>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</array>
```

Delete that from the XML document and then consume the altered document using:

```
pwpolicy -setaccountpolicies <file.xml>
```

and the problem should go away. But there is a pitfall. If you dump the XML using the shell's `>` operator, edit the file, and pass it back to `pwpolicy`, you'll get this error:

```
Error: The data is not in the correct format.
```

The reason for this error is that `pwpolicy -getaccountpolicies` prints the following before printing the XML:

```
Getting global account policies
```

Comment: Do you remember whether you **set** this policy in the past?

Comment: I know for a fact that I did not set this policy. I wasn't even aware of the `pwpolicy` tool until you mentioned it.

Comment: @klanomath I edited it. (extra text to reach required length)