# Make password policy permanent

Tags: macos, security, password

Mac keeps resetting my password policy leading to an annoying password reset...

See the question [How to force the Mac to not expire passwords?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287217/how-to-force-the-mac-to-not-expire-passwords) on how to change the password policy. This is however not persistent.

How do I make the password policy permanent?

**EDIT**

In response to the comment, here is the output of

```sh
pwpolicy -u $USER --get-effective-policy
```

```sh
isDisabled=false newPasswordRequired=false
```

I just upgraded the MacBook Pro to `13.1`. Before I was on BigSur.
The machine is no longer managed, it got a fresh OS reinstall a while back.

Comment: As asked in the linked question - is this a work computer that is 'managed' by software? Please open Terminal and enter `pwpolicy -u $USER --get-effective-policy` and add the result to your question. A Mac doesn't force password changes by default. Also, what Mac model; what OS version?

Comment: @benwiggy any comment on the output you wanted to see?

Comment: That's the default output, so something else must be causing it. Note that a 'simple' reinstall will not necessarily remove device management controls. What is the password for -- user account? Do you have any software like 1Password?

Comment: @benwiggy before the reinstall was done, there was some software installed which prompted me for my organization password before I was able to choose my account. Any other idea how I could find the cause?